# R: How can I make this function output each list element value subtracted from the first list element value?

Tags: r, oop

I am having some trouble with a function that I created in R.

```
fixed <- c("", "disp", "hp", "wt", "qsec", "vs")

f <- function(v) {
  fo <- reformulate(c(setdiff(fixed, v),"hp" ), "mpg")
   cat("Running", format(fo), "\n")
   rf <- lm(fo, data = mtcars)
   matrix_coef <- summary(rf)$coefficients
   full_coef <- sum(matrix_coef[ , 1])
 }

out <- Map(f, fixed)
```

Whenever you run this function it gives you the following list:

```
> out

[[1]]
[1] 28.449

$disp
[1] 24.99826

$hp
[1] 28.449

$wt
[1] 56.23431

$qsec
[1] 35.58044

$vs
[1] 32.71946
```

**How can I** make this function output each list element value subtracted from the first list element value "[[1]]"? So that each of the element values that are in this list are subtracted by the first list element titled "[[1]]".

```
[[1]]
[1] 28.449

######## All of the list elements values below should be subtracted from "[[1]]"

$disp
[1] 24.99826

$hp
[1] 28.449

$wt
[1] 56.23431

$qsec
[1] 35.58044

$vs
[1] 32.71946
```

Basically, the formula would be ([[1]] - x) with x being any other element value included in our list.

```
[[1]] - $disp

[[1]] - $hp

[[1]] - $wt

[[1]] - $qsec

[[1]] - $vs
```

For example, the list would contain the differences obtained above.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for `out[[1]] - unlist(out[-1])`?

Comment: @Rui Barradas Would it be possible to do this inside of the function? How can I get "out" to exist inside the function before running it? Is it possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible, you are passing the function one element of `fixed` at a time, the rest of the list doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to define within your function a function to calculate the coefficient and than writing something like `return(calcCoef("")-calcCoef(v))`, e.g.:

```
f <- function(v) {
  
  calcCoef <- function(symbol){
    fo <- reformulate(c(setdiff(fixed, symbol),"hp" ), "mpg")
    cat("Running", format(fo), "\n")
    rf <- lm(fo, data = mtcars)
    matrix_coef <- summary(rf)$coefficients
    full_coef_h <- sum(matrix_coef[ , 1])
    return(full_coef_h)
  }
  return(calcCoef("")-calcCoef(v))
}
```

fixed should be than something like: `fixed <- c("disp", "hp", "wt", "qsec", "vs")`

Comment: Masterful, thanks so much!